# Spoofing bytes of a UDP checksum over network

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to play with a security tool using scapy to spoof ASCII characters in a UDP checksum.  I can do it, but only when I hardcode the bytes in Hex notation.  But I can't convert the ASCII string word into binary notation.  This works to send the bytes of "He" (first two chars of "Hello world"):
`sr1(IP(dst=server)/UDP(dport=53, chksum=0x4865)/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname=query)),verbose=0)`

But whenever I try to use a variable of `test2` instead of `0x4865`, the DNS packet is not transmitted over the network.  This should create binary for this ASCII:

`test2 = bin(int(binascii.hexlify('He'),16))`

`sr1(IP(dst=server)/UDP(dport=53, chksum=test2)/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname=query)),verbose=0)`

When I print test2 variable is shows correct binary notation representation.

How do I convert a string such as `He` so that is shows in the checksum notation accepted by scapy, of `0x4865` ??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by removing the bin().  This works:

`test2 = int(binascii.hexlify('He'),16)`